# Troubles with own types in Qi

Tags: ccl, qi

I've vainly tried to get the type declaration examples working with Clozure CL, e.g. the following:

```
(datatype fruit
   if (element? F [apples pears oranges])
   ______________________________________
   F : fruit;)
```

but the only output I get is:

```
type error
```

It seems to be a problem with Ccl, is there any possibility that it runs properly?

P.S.: Type checking is turned on, (tc +)

Answer (score 1):

That works for me on QiII1.06SBCL:

```
(0-) (tc +)
true

(1+) (datatype fruit
       if (element? F [apples pears oranges])
       ______________________________________
       F : fruit;)
fruit : symbol

(2+) apples : fruit
apples : fruit

(3+) steak : fruit
type error
```

So I'd suggest that you try and download one of the official bundles from the website, because, as far as I know, CCL is not officially supported at the moment.